# Multiplying an array of vectors by each other

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have three time series arrays a, b, c consisting of 1000 values each. They make up a matrix A.

Now, I want to take each array and pointwise multiply it to every other array so that I will get  9 new vectors a^2, ab, ac, ba, b^2, bc, ca, cb, cc.

When I've done this, I want to combine these 9 new arrays into 81 new.

How do I do this? Like I said, I tried building a matrix but it doesnt work the way I wanted it to. I want A to be recognized as a 1*3-matrix contaning 1000*1-arrays. As it is now it just concatenates everything. If A was a 1*3 matrix containing arrays, I could just build the matrix B = transpose(A) * A which would contain all products

I've tried things like

```
A = [[a] [b] [c]]

A = {a b c}

A = {a; b; c}
defining a, b and c as a = {1, 2, 5, 2 , 1 ...} instead of [1, 2, 5, 2 , 1 ...]
```

but none of them works.

I don't care if a, b, c, d is stored as lists, column arrays, row arrays or cells, and I'm really not good enough at matlab to know the all the subtile differences, but speed and memory performance is sort of an issue.

Comment: Place a dot `.` before a matrix operator to make it element-wise, e.g. `a.^2`, `a.*b`.

Comment: Sorry, but I want the arrays to be multiplied by each other, not by themself. Maybe I wan't clear enough, but I'm looking for some sort of automatic way to combine the arrays. In reality, I'm gonna have more than three signals, possibly hundreds, so it will be too tedious to just write it out for each combo.

I want the calculation performed element-wise, but first i want the arrays combined "matrix-wise".

Comment: Ideally, I would like to have a matrix that behaves mathematically exactly as a matrix, except that it has arrays (or lists, or vectors) as entries and + and * is overloaded

It would be great if I could do matrix multiplication too, such that the first entry of A*B is a11 * b12 + a12 * b21, where a11 etc is a vector and a11 * b12 is piecewise multiplication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem reduces down to creating index pairs.

```
%Simulate random data
X=rand(1000,3); 

%Create index multiplication pairs
[i,j] = meshgrid(1:size(X,2),1:size(X,2))

%Multiply together
X = X(:,i(:)).*X(:,j(:));
```

In this case you will get the following pairs of columns multiplied together

```
[i(:)';j(:)'] = 
1     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     3
1     2     3     1     2     3     1     2     3
```

You can repeat the process to remultiply. Be careful though: the matrix size will grow exponentially in the number of iterations.

Comment: thanks, this seem to do exactly what I want. I have no idea what happens on the last line but it works.
Any idea on what do to with the above problem of having matrices that work on arrays instead of numbers? (i didn't create a new question because it's sort of related).

Comment: @user1661303 please mark this as the correct answer if it satisfies your initial question. Regarding your second question: You will need to rephrase your question because it is not clear to me what you mean.

Comment: Marked. The other question was in the initial post which was why I didn't mark it as solved yet. I want the matrix to behave as a 1*3 matrix, only the 3 entries shouldn't be numbers but arrays, ie i want to encapsulate the arrays. But maybe it was too vaguely formulated. Will post a new question about it tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as follows. Since the functions [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) may not be obvious for a Matlab beginner, I suggest you take a look at their doc if needed (see links above).

Given the three data vectors `a`, `b`, `c`, proceed as follows:

```
A = [ a(:) b(:) c(:) ]; % matrix from column vectors
P = bsxfun(@times,A,permute(A,[1 3 2])); % desired result
```

The result `P` is a 1000x3x3 array that contains the desired products. The second and third indices of `P` are interpreted in the obvious way: 1 corresponds to  `a`, 2 to `b` and 3 to `c`. For example, `P(10,1,2)` is `a(10)*b(10)`; `P(50,3,3)` is `c(50)^2`; and so on.

To iterate: simply [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) `P` into a new `A2` matrix and repeat procedure:

```
A2 = reshape(P,[1000,9,1]);
P2 = bsxfun(@times,A2,permute(A2,[1 3 2])); % result
```

This gives the result in the 1000x9x9 array `P2`.